# Need to change date format of the xml value

Tags: xml, plsql

I want to change the date format of the "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" xml tag value. can any one please help me out.

Actual output:

```
<MESSAGE>
<LOCATIONS>
  <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
  <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
  <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
  <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>   
  <LAST_MODIFIED_DATE>23-Dec-2017</LAST_MODIFIED_DATE>
</LOCATIONS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Expected output:

```
<MESSAGE>
<LOCATIONS>
  <LOCATION_ID>9999</LOCATION_ID>
  <LOC_TYPE>S</LOC_TYPE>
  <NAME>Test Location</NAME> 
  <PHONE_NUM>08 </PHONE_NUM>
  <LAST_MODIFIED_DATE>12/23/2017</LAST_MODIFIED_DATE>
</LOCATIONS>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: How did you get your XML? can you use PLSQL functions when you get it from DB?

Answer (score 0):

Through the below type we have the loaded data in xml :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE MESSAGE
    AS
       OBJECT (
              Location_ID         NUMBER,
              Loc_type            VARCHAR2(20),
              Name                VARCHAR2(20),
              phone_num           VARCHAR2(20),
              Last_modified       DATE
              );
    /

declare
 l_sql    VARCHAR2(2000);
 l_test_t MESSAGE:= MESSAGE();
 l_to_xml   xmltype;
begin
 l_test_t.Location_ID := 9999;
 l_test_t.Loc_type := 'S';
 l_test_t.Name := 'Test Location';
 l_test_t.phone_num := '08';
 l_test_t.Last_modified := Sysdate;
 l_to_xml := XMLTYPE(l_test_t);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_to_xml.getstringval);
end;
```

we cant able to change the type structure. so i need any other option to change the date format.

Comment: sorry I do not have PL/SQL in hands, but how about `alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy'` ? ... Anyway both your values are not in XML `date` format